# fdisk -l shows my drive as /dev/sdb not /dev/sdb1

Tags: fdisk

So `fdisk -l` shows it as `/dev/sdb`. Shouldn't it be showing as `/dev/sdb1`? ...or perhaps `/dev/sdb0`?
What I'm up to is adding a drive to my system. Everything else is LVM so that is what I want here too. I've already figured out how to create the physical volume and add it to the volume group but IDK why it's showing up as `/dev/sdb`. I don't remember ever seeing that. So far, I've been using [this](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager) as my guide.

Comment: If there is no partition on your device, you see only sdb (which represent device) then, partitions will be listed as sdb1, sdb2,.... Are you sure you have some partition on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disk is `/dev/sdb` and the partitions, when created, on the disk will be `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2` and so on. So until you create partition with gparted, parted, fdisk of other tool, you will only have `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that I missed a step in the instructions that mentions creating one with cfdisk.